# Difference between O(logn) and O(nlogn)

Tags: big-o

I am preparing for software development interviews, I always faced the problem in distinguishing the difference between O(logn) and O(nLogn). Can anyone explain me with some examples or share some resource with me. I don't have any code to show. I understand O(Logn) but I haven't understood O(nlogn).

Comment: It's the same as the difference between O(1) and O(n) or the difference between O(n) and O(n^2).

Comment: Check out https://www.quora.com/How-are-O-logn-and-O-nlogn-calculated

Comment: You still need to study a lot. O(..) describes the complexity of your algorithm. To be easy, you can imagine as the time to take to finish you algorithm for an n input, if O(n) it will finish in n seconds, O(logn) will finish in logn seconds and n*logn seconds for O(nlogn). O(1) means the cost of your algorithm is constant no matter how big n is.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Think of it as `O(n*log(n))`, i.e. "doing `log(n)` work `n` times". For example, searching for an element in a sorted list of length `n` is `O(log(n))`. Searching for the element in `n` different sorted lists, each of length `n` is `O(n*log(n))`.

Remember that `O(n)` is defined *relative to some real quantity n*. This might be the size of a list, or the number of different elements in a collection. Therefore, every variable that appears inside `O(...)` represents something interacting to increase the runtime. `O(n*m)` could be written `O(n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_m)` and represent the same thing: "doing `n`, `m` times".

Let's take a concrete example of this, `mergesort`. For `n` input elements: On the very last iteration of our sort, we have two halves of the input, each half size `n/2`, and each half is sorted. All we have to do is merge them together, which takes `n` operations. On the next-to-last iteration, we have twice as many pieces (4) each of size `n/4`. For each of our two pairs of size `n/4`, we merge the pair together, which takes `n/2` operations for a pair (one for each element in the pair, just like before), i.e. `n` operations for the two pairs.

From here, we can extrapolate that every level of our mergesort takes `n` operations to merge. The big-O complexity is therefore `n` times *the number of levels*. On the last level, the size of the chunks we're merging is `n/2`. Before that, it's `n/4`, before that `n/8`, etc. all the way to size `1`. How many times must you divide `n` by 2 to get `1`? `log(n)`. So we have `log(n)` levels. Therefore, our total runtime is `O(n (work per level) * log(n) (number of levels))`, `n` work `log(n)` times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow up question for you. Can you prove that how time complexity of merge sort is O(nLogn)? Please don't use the master theorem while explaining the reasoning. Please share any resource which you think is useful.

Comment: You're welcome. I *could* do an outright proof, but it doesn't really belong in this question, and there are a million other proofs on Google. Instead, I'll add mergesort as an example in my question, and I think that will work to show you *how* to prove its runtime, as well.

Comment: Yeah.. I think there is no need. I have got some of my basics right. I will work from here.. Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: I am trying to understand this as well.  Perhaps I don't understand it because many say the O(n log n) boils down to O(log n).  I disagree since O(n log n) has a higher time complexity than O(n) while (log n) has a lower time complexity than O(n).  Take for example O(1000 * log base 2 1000) that would be (1000 * 10) which is 10,000.  So, in this case O(n) is 1000, O(log n) is 10, and O(n log n) is 10,000.  That's a significant difference to me.

Comment: @FernandoZ "because many say the O(n log n) boils down to O(log n)" -> they're wrong.  Your intuition is good, but it's not actually the difference for any given value of `n` that makes them wrong. It's that the limit as n approaches infinity of `(n*log(n) / log(n))` is infinity, not constant. That means as n approaches infinity, `n*log(n)` will grow infinitely larger than  `log(n)`. The reason any specific value doesn't matter is that `O(n + 999,999,999) == O(n * 999,999,999) == O(n)` - differences in value can be caused by constants, ignored because they do not change the limit calculation